# GCP load balancer with on prem resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load, load-balancing

I am looking to create a load balancer with on premise machines behind it

I have looked at the load balancer and backend service configuration but can't seem to figure it out

Looking to create the GCP http load balancer that will server requests to on premise machines not gcp vms

Comment: Which type of load balancer do you want to use ? Which kind of port do you want to forward ?

Comment: guillame i have 2 on premise servers i want to test. I like to see if I can put a load balancer in GCP and point/put the servers behind it. I believe that GCP Cloud Load Balancer does not allow this but was wondering if there is another way to do this.

Comment: I tested a lot of things, without success.. Sorry... The easiest solution is to use LVS on a VM instance. But it's not Google LoadBalancing, it's your own load balancing...